# Python tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a container with a set of frames, that provide me with two pages (main page and an info page.) Buttons are used to navigate the pages.
All is working.

I have defined a function to remove folders on the OS. (shutil.rmtree) This function should be called by my button 2 on the main page, but it falls over and is not working.

```
 import tkinter as tk
 import shutil
 from tkinter import *


 TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")


 class App(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

         # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
         # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
         # will be raised above the others
         container = tk.Frame(self)
         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
         container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
         container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

         self.frames = {}
         for F in (MainPage, InfoPage,):
             frame = F(container, self)
             self.frames[F] = frame
             # put all of the pages in the same location;
             # the one on the top of the stacking order
             # will be the one that is visible.
             frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

         self.show_frame(MainPage)

     def show_frame(self, c):
         '''Show a frame for the given class'''
         frame = self.frames[c]
         frame.tkraise()


 class MainPage(tk.Frame):

     def callback(self):
         shutil.rmtree('C:\Test', ignore_errors=False)

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         self.controller = controller
         photo = PhotoImage(file='C:\Logo.gif')
         label = Label(self, image=photo)
         label.Image = photo
         label.pack(side=TOP)
         button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Info!",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(InfoPage))
         button1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
         button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Clean!", command=callback)
         button2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)


 class InfoPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         self.controller = controller
         label = tk.Label(self, text="Info Page", font=TITLE_FONT)
         label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
         button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
         button.pack()


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = App()
     app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should set the action of button2 the same way you do it with f.e. button1. callbacks are functions with no arguments, but you provide a function with one argument. ... also try to strip your code down to the minimum, it would be much easier to find out what your exact problem is when there were only a few lines of code.

Comment: I still cant get it right...its driving me nuts!

Comment: getting "callback is not defined"

Comment: try this: `tk.Button(self, text="Clean!", command=lambda: self.callback())`

Comment: That got it! Thanks! :)

Comment: How would I add several paths to the shutil.rmtree operation? I just used one path to get it working, but would need to add at least three different paths to folders?

Comment: I look at the docs here, (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) but no mention of multiple paths.... I guess it's just my newbie ignorance!

Comment: @linluk: if you aren't passing any arguments, there's absolutely no reason to use `lambda`. These two are exactly equivalent: `command=self.callback`, `command=lambda: self.callback())`. `lambda`  adds complexity without adding any value in this case.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh, i just tried it and you are right. i once ran into a similar issue and from that on i always used lambda here. thanks :-)